# Traduzione di "ground truth" nell'ambito del machine learning

Tags: translation

In diversi ambiti scientifici è molto usato il concetto di "**ground truth**", cioè di dati empirici "veri", raccolti tramite osservazione diretta, che di solito vengono usati per confermare o sfatare delle ipotesi inferenziali.

Nelle mie ricerche non sono riuscito a trovare una traduzione soddisfacente di questo termine in italiano. Su [Linguee](http://www.linguee.it/inglese-italiano/traduzione/ground+truth.html), l'unico sito dove ho trovato qualcosa, la traduzione è "dati di campo", ma tutte le occorrenze provenivano dalla traduzione dello stesso articolo scientifico, e sinceramente mi sembra una traduzione piuttosto grezza. Quindi la mia domanda è:

C'è un modo più o meno universalmente riconosciuto per tradurre "**ground truth**" in un articolo scientifico in italiano?

Comment: Potrebbe essere tradotto con **conoscenze acquisite sul campo** oppure **conoscenze di prima mano**.

Comment: Potrebbe essere anche tradotto come dati di 'verità a terra'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non credo che esista una traduzione universalmente accettata, e il *machine learning* è un campo molto specialistico in cui spesso si ricorre al semplice uso dei termini inglesi. Possiedo un solo libro sull'apprendimento automatico in Italiano (Eliano Pessoa, Statistica con le Reti Neurali) e l'autore non fa menzione, per quanto ne sappia, di *ground truth*, limitandosi ad individuare un *insieme di addestramento* (*training set*).

Detto questo, spesso la base di dati con cui si addestra un algoritmo supervisionato, o la conoscenza a priori di cui ci si serve per testare la capacità predittiva di algoritmi non supervisionati vengono definiti *knowledge base*, e si traduce come *base di conoscenza* o *conoscenza di base*.

Un esempio dell'uso di *conoscenza di base* è [questo articolo di Wikipedia sull'"Apprendimento automatico"](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprendimento_automatico). Ma il termine e' una traduzione dall'inglese *background knowledge*.

Al contrario *base di conoscenza* viene [riconosciuto da Wikipedia come traduzione diretta di "knowledge base"](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_di_conoscenza).

Non ho trovato riferimenti diretti alla traduzione di *ground truth*, e la voce Wikipedia dispone di traduzioni esclusivamente in [Tedesco](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_Truth) e in [Catalano](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veritat_terreny), e in entrambi i casi la traduzione sembra abbastanza letterale, forse perché si riferisce all'applicazione geografica e cartografica del termine.

Quindi non credo esista una traduzione del termine **riconosciuta** universalmente, ma nell'ambito dell'apprendimento automatico suggerirei l'uso di "base di conoscenza".